# How to rank multiple columns on excel. I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following input data:

| Contamination | 10% | 10% | 20% | 20% | 30% | 30% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Estimator** | **Trial 1** | **Trial 2** | **Trial 1** | **Trial 2** | **Trial 1** | **Trial 2** |
| OLA | 500 | 75 | 100 | 430 | 460 | 230 |
| PWA | 360 | 457 | 400 | 200 | 200 | 400 |
| CA | 470 | 270 | 450 | 250 | 350 | 150 |
| HA | 215 | 310 | 200 | 400 | 400 | 200 |
| AM | 300 | 500 | 315 | 200 | 500 | 250 |

Table has `5` different estimators each having `2` repeated trials for each of the `3` groups of percentages of contaminations (`10%`, `20%`, and `30%`) considered.

For each of the `5` estimators (in my real problem I have more than `5`), I want to rank (from lower to highest value) among the trials within each group of percentages (in my real problem I have more than `3`) simultaneously.

I am looking for a solution, that doesn't require manually to rank each group, since in my real problem I have a larger group of percentages, trials per group and experiments. The number of trials within each group are the same.

I want to get a formula that can rank it simultaneously. Here is the expected output from the input data sample:

| Contamination | 10% | 10% | 20% | 20% | 30% | 30% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Estimator** | **Trial 1** | **Trial 2** | **Trial 1** | **Trial 2** | **Trial 1** | **Trial 2** |
| OLA | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| PWA | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| CA | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| HA | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| AM | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

**Notes**:

- I have an older version of Excel: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016, please consider that in your answer
- The Contamination is the same within the trial set (**Trial 1**, **Trial 2**). Table Markdown feature doesn't allow to merge cells, that is why the percentage is repeated

Comment: Son rank based on one column, max of 3 values across 3 columns or the sum of all 3 columns.

Comment: Are these tables always the same dimension?  5 Estimators, 3 percentages, 2 phases?  Also, this would be easy to do with the array functions in O365 excel, but it won't be a single-formula solution in Excel 2016.

Comment: Your title says **Excel 2016**. Why have you also tagged it with `excel-2007` and `excel-2010`?  Also, please edit your question to show what you have tried and where you have run into problems. It might be useful to read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you say: "I have more than 50 of them", do you mean estimators, percentage of contaminators group or trials within each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume from your question:

> I do not want to rank them individually as it will take much time
> since I have more than 50 of them to rank

You are referring to the percentage groups and/or number of trials that can be large, which is the most difficult task to expand.

In the cell `L3`(see screenshot below) I put the first formula that can be expanded vertically and horizontally. *Please pay attention to the `$` mark to ensure it works in both directions*.

```
=RANK(OFFSET($C3,0, L$2*$J$2 + L$1), 
  OFFSET($C3,0, L$2*$J$2,1,$J$2),1)
```

Using named ranges, for example naming `$J$2` as `totalTrials` it is easier to understand the formula:

```
=RANK(OFFSET($C3,0, L$2*$totalTrials + L$1), 
  OFFSET($C3,0, L$2*totalTrials,1,totalTrials),1)
```

or even better, using the modern `LET` function to define all the variables first, is the easiest way to read it:

```
=LET(startCell,$C3, totalTrials,$J$2, 
  groupCnt, L$2*totalTrials, trialCnt,L$1, 
    RANK(OFFSET(startCell,0, groupCnt + trialCnt), 
      OFFSET(startCell,0, groupCnt,1,totalTrials),1)
 )
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

Changing the values of **Trial per Group** (`J2`) or **# Groups** (`J4`) and expanding the formula horizontally and vertically you can consider a large number of trials within the group, large number of groups and a large number of experiments.

### Explanation

For doing the ranking per experiment within the group I use the `RANK(number,ref,order)`. For jumping from one group to another and getting the specific trial within the group, the `OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, height, width)` function. (check this [link](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-offset-function) for more information about `OFFSET` function).

For building the recurrence in the formula I use the following two helper rows:

1. `L1:Q1`: The trial number within the group, starting from zero, via the following formula: `MOD((COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1),$J$2)`. It generates the sequence: `0,1,2,...N, 0,1,2,..N`, where `N` is the number of trials minus one (easier to start from zero for the recurrence). In the sample the number of trials is indicated in the cell: `J2`.
2. `L2:Q2`: The group number, starting from zero, that each trial belongs to via the following formula: `INT((COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1)/($J$2))`. It generates the sequence: `0,0,0,..0, 1,1,1,..1,...M,M,M...M`, where each number is repeated as many times as trials we have where `M` is the number of groups minus one.

**Note**: There is a more concise way for building such sequences in modern excel versions via `SEQUENCE` but you indicated you have an older version.

In order to generate both sequences, I took the idea from here: [Excel Magic Trick 692: More About Incrementing Numbers In Formulas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIQbJAPMrEg&t=0s) (that works for older excel versions)

Combining properly both helper rows in `OFFSET`, the rank is calculated per trial per experiment.

This explanatory picture from ExcelJet, helps to understand each input argument of the `OFFSET` function:

[image: OFFSET explanation from ExcelJet]

Comment: Hello, good day sir.
I want to, first of all, appreciate you for answering my question. This has been a challenge to me for the past few months. However, after doing it the way you suggested, I got an error which I believe is from my side. Below is what I got

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot post a picture in the comment box. What I actually mean by ‘’I have more than 50 of them to rank’’ is that; the number of groups is more than 50, the number of trials per group is up to 6, the number of estimators is 140 and I have more than 100 such tables to rank.
Please if the newer version of excel can do this task with ease, do suggest the particular version so that I will see how I can get one installed on my PC.
Sir, please help me out to get this problem solved as it has hooked me up for months with no progress.

Comment: Please I will like to post the picture of the excel output I got using the method you suggested. I wrote everything as you asked me to but yet I could not arrive at a table like yours above.

Comment: I understand @AliyuUmar. You can upload the image to the cloud (Dropbox, One drive, etc.) then share the public link in the comment as a link like this: `[Title](URl)`. Check the help link  (bottom right corner of the comment box), while you are  writing the comment.

Comment: it has worked perfectly. You forgot to put an equal sign in the formula; MOD((COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1),$J$2, and INT((COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1)/($J$2)) that's why, but when I put equal signs in the two formulas it works.